# Django aggregation by the name of day

Tags: python, django

I've tried make 'day of week aggregation', I have this code:

IN:

```
MyMode.objects.values('day').annotate(Sum('visits'))
```

OUT:

```
[{'visits__sum': 44, 'day': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 5, 0, 0)},
{'visits__sum': 699, 'day': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 6, 0, 0)},     
{'visits__sum': 3, 'day': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 3, 0, 0)}, 
{'visits__sum': 12, 'day': datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 5, 0, 0)}]
```

But I want to aggregate by the name of day, not the number.
I need totally visits in Monday, Tuesday, etc. Monday from 2015.08 should be in the same 'bag' where Monday from 2015.06 or 2012.02.

Comment: Which db backend you are using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.8+:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class DayOfWeek(Func):
    """ Sunday == 0, ..., Saturday == 6 """
    template = 'extract(dow from %(expressions)s)'

>>> (
    MyMode.objects.annotate(dow=DayOfWeek(F('day')))
                  .values('dow')
                  .annotate(c=Count('dow'))
)

[{'c': 185, 'dow': 0.0}, {'c': 178, 'dow': 5.0}]
```

For Django 1.7-, I believe you need to do a raw query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the solution you are expecting for, but maybe can help you:

for Sundays:

```
MyMode.objects.values('day').annotate(Sum('visits')).filter(day__week_day=1)
```

Change the filter value for the other weekend days. Days starts in `Sunday=1, Monday=2,` etc.